# Taking code section from branch in "diffs" view in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to take a code from the compared branch in the 'diff' view in Visual Studio 2022 in a similar way to JetBrains Rider? In Rider, I can view 'diffs' and take a code section/line from the branch ie. if I want to revert some changes to the original state. Is it possible in VS?

[image]

Comment: I found that JetBrains Fleet also supports this function.